# Does using Webview to open mobile page count as in-app purchase?

Tags: android, android-webview, in-app-billing

I read the agreements on Android Developer site already but I dont clearly understand it.

From what I understand. If I want to allow user to purchase/subscribe my service through my Android application, I must offer Google Checkout as an option. I'm not in a supported country for Merchant account, so that option is not available to me. Am I allow to use third party library without offering Checkout option?

If I use Webview inside that application to open a page on my website, does that count as in-app purchase?

I searched for similar question but not really sure if the Webview violate the agreement or not?

Comment: I dont think it violates the agreement because it's not a part of the app itself, but good question I was going to do something similar, so i'm gonna wait for an answer here :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a legal question. Please address it to Google directly as only they can give you an authoritative answer about android market terms of use.

Comment: I was going to do that until I found a similar question asked on Android discussion group left unanswered. Market Developer support doesn't provide support over this kind of topic as well. I'll file it under publishing support and see how it goes.